# ArCore - Create anchor in context of Session

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to create an anchor in the context of session rather than trackable planes. I want to know whether these 2 statements are same or they are different in creating anchors in different context?

```
arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
            (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {

                Anchor anchor = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().createAnchor(hitResult.getHitPose());
                Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
                AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
});
```

I believe Statement 1 i.e

```
Anchor anchor = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().createAnchor(hitResult.getHitPose());
```

creates anchor in context of session

and Statement 2 i.e

```
Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
```

create anchor in context of planes / trackables

Am I correct?

Comment: did you find an answer to this yet? I am trying to do similar thing.

Comment: Statement 1 creates an anchor for the current session from the given HitResult. You have probably got a HitResut before from tapping a plane, it is an arg for the `OnTapArPlaneListener#onTapPlane` fn. You actually just want to create a Pose (presumably just the Camera's pose but a few meters away from you), and then use this and the session to create an anchor, like so: `session.createAnchor(pose);`- the only hard part is deciding 'how far away' to place your item. Lots of people recommend doing Ray Tests to find a suitable real object to fix your anchor to - this is more complex but more real